# The "Nascent Sanhedrin" - what is the position of gedolim on it?

Tags: sanhedrin, latid-lavo-future

There has been an attempt to re-establish the Sanhendrin, starting around 2004.

http://www.thesanhedrin.org/en/index.php/The_Re-established_Jewish_Sanhedrin
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_attempt_to_revive_the_Sanhedrin
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_attempts_to_revive_the_Sanhedrin

What positions have gedolei Yisroel taken on this attempt?
(I see that the first Wikipedia article has some answers to this question.)

Comment: I think Rabbi Steinsaltz supported them somewhat, but I'm pretty the rest of the big-name rabbis pretty much ignored them. But maybe Rabbi Aviner wrote about them somewhere...

Comment: According to everything I've seen, Rabbi Steinsaltz was their _nasi_, then resigned in 2008. One source said that it was he who insisted on the more humble names like "Nascent" Sandhedrin.

Comment: Okay, so there was him.

Comment: Here are a couple of short articles by Rabbi Aviner: http://shlomo-aviner.net/index.php?title=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9_(%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8) and https://www.srugim.co.il/348021-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%95

Comment: As someone who followed this from the beginning, there were many Gedolei Yisrael who supported the effort. Some did not. I believe Rabbi David Bar Chaim of Machon Shilo was asked to join and ultimately declined. I believe because he saw lack of support. To my knowledge, it has dissolved at this point. They used to list rulings they had made and their various activities on their website. It has been non-functional for years.

Comment: For details: http://www.thesanhedrin.org/en/index.php/The_Nascent_Sanhedrin#In_the_news

Comment: @YaacovDeane Those details are supplied by the organization itself. I was looking for what others say. As for being disbanded, my son in the Mir assured me that he knows one of them and they are apparently still operating.

Comment: I’m glad to hear it but surprised that they have had no web updates since 2007. If you go to the Machon Shilo YouTube channel and search for Nascent Sanhedrin, you might find the Rav discussing his views on it (if it is still posted there).

Comment: I forgot which gadol they asked to head it, and he basically told them that if he agreed, his first act would be to disband it.

Comment: AFAIK, most Charedi gedolim just ignored them completely.